# Setting remote Ansible variable when using Packer Ansible Remote Provisioner

Tags: ansible, packer

I am calling this playbook from my Packer script.

```
  hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
  - name: Install Sophos
    include_role:
      name: install_sophos
```

Because I am using the Ansible Remote Provisioner for Packer I understand I don't have `{{role_path` and `{{ansible_env.HOME}}` set on the remote EC2 instance I'm building. I am confused as to how best to pass these or whether the control host should have this information. Below is a snippet of `task/main.yml` under my roles.

```
- name: Copy sophos script to server
  copy:
    src: "{{ role_path }}/files/SophosInstall.sh"
    dest: "{{ ansible_env.HOME }}/SophosInstall.sh"
    mode: 0775
  register: si
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `vars` section

```
  hosts: all
  become: true
  remote_user: ubuntu
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
  - name: Install Sophos
    include_role:
      name: install_sophos
    vars:
      role:
        template: true
```

and I had to update the user because I'm running from my home directory which doesn't exist on the EC2 instance which is the line `remote_user: ubuntu`